# What would happen if the atmosphere were compressed until it has the density of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, estimation, density

> What would happen if the atmosphere were compressed until it has the density of water?

If the atmosphere were compressed to the density of water, it would be covered by a layer of height, say $h$. Note that I know this actually wouldn't be possible but I'm curious on what the height would be, since from a lot of research it says to be $10$ meters but I'm unable to see how?

What I thought was that in the inside of the layer the Pascal's principle would satisfy then $$P_{inside}=P_{atm}+\rho_{H_2 O}gh$$ since we labelling the layer of height $h$, and the outside of the layer still has that atmospheric pressure, doesn't it? Hence the height of that layer: $$h=\frac{P_{inside}-P_{atm}}{g\rho_{H_2 0}}$$ but we don't know the pressure inside, do we? And I've also seen people doing this with the pressure of mercury which seems shocking to me, so I was wondering how you would happen to know that height of that new formed layer.

Comment: If it were all water, 10 meters is about right. Since N2 and O2 are heavier then water, it is more like 6 meters and a bit, modulo relative densities of water and liquid nitrogen-oxygen.

Comment: note that mercury is 13.5x as dense as water, so atmospheric pressure (about 30 inches of Hg), is about 30 feet of water. maybe a little more.